# Why jQuery.each doesn't loop through all items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems like .each function does not loop properly trough all items when there are variable set inside .each function, assuming this as the reason that items do not get removed.
But 2nd function I've used to test loop shows that it should work.

Any special reasson?

HTML Code:

```
<div id="top-menu">
    <ul id="top-menu-main-ul">
        <li class="top-menu-main-li">
            <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
            <div class="arrow-bg-above-ul"> </div>
            <ul class="top-menu-child-ul">
                <li class="top-li-ztyle"><a class="menu-item-2" href="index.php">Admin Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-item-2" href="myaccount.php">My Account</a></li>
                <li class="bottom-li-ztyle"><a class="menu-item-0" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="top-menu-main-li">
            <span class="separator"><a href="#" title="Clients">Clients</a></span>
            <div class="arrow-bg-above-ul"> </div>
            <ul class="top-menu-child-ul">
                <li class="top-li-ztyle"><a class="menu-item-3" href="clients.php">View/Search Clients</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-item-4" href="clientsadd.php">Add New Client</a></li>
                <li class="bottom-li-ztyle"><a class="menu-item-5" href="massmail.php">Mass Mail Clients</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
var arrayOfitems = ["1","2","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","77"];

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".top-menu-child-ul li a").each(function() {
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var thisClassNum = thisClass.replace('menu-item-', '');
        var searchForThisNum = thisClassNum.toString();     

        if($.inArray(searchForThisNum, arrayOfitems) !== -1 )
        {
           // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            $("." + thisClass).closest('.li').remove();
        }
    });


    // test that loop should work
    var myArray = [];

    $(".top-menu-child-ul li a").each(function() {
       myArray.push($(this).attr('class'));
    });

    alert(myArray);
});
```

Fiddle Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/LmUPL/2/

Comment: what do you mean by 'does not loop properly'? Elements doesn't get removed?

Comment: these demos you create are not representative of the problems you have. If fiddle does what you expect....how are we to understand what the problem is? Be more specific about why you say it's not looping properly...on quick glance is hard for others to follow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to find `class="li"` ancestors to remove:

```
$("." + thisClass).closest('.li').remove();
// -------------------------^
```

You mean to say:

```
$("." + thisClass).closest('li').remove();
```

to find the `<li>`s. Also, as noted by [Juan Guerrero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009119/juan-guerrero) in the comments, I think you want to say this:

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

to make sure you target exactly the right element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/A7Ys2/2/

Comment: Man I looked through this twice and couldn't see it. Nice catch.

Comment: Also, I would add that $("." + thisClass) isn't necessary as you can reuse the $(this)

Comment: This is it, Pro. Edit your own fiddle and see the difference.

Comment: @JuanGuerrero: Excellent point. There will be cases where things like `$('.' + thisClass)` will match too many elements and thus remove too much.

Comment: @muistooshort That wouldn't be the case here, as the op is using class in anchors more like ids, but I agree with you.

It was more something like, man, you have jquerified (if that's a thing) the element, don't do the job twice.

Comment: @JuanGuerrero: I was thinking more along the lines of a class selector being broader than expected. I routinely `var $x = $(x)` so I didn't even notice the over-jQuerification.